# Converting Unformatted String Of Objects Into An Array

Tags: ruby, string

I simply want to convert a string like this:

```
str = "tree dog orange music apple"
```

Into an array like this:

```
arr = ["tree", "dog", "orange", "music", "apple"]
```

I tried going down a path like this before realizing it's a dead end:

```
str = "tree dog orange music apple"
# => "tree dog orange music apple"
str.gsub!(" ", ", ")
# => "tree, dog, orange, music, apple"
arr = str.to_a
# ["tree, dog, orange, music, apple"]
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The String [split](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000803) method will do nicely:

`str.split(' ')`

Answer (score 1):

array = str.split

Answer (score 0):

Also of potential interest:

```
arr = %w{tree dog orange music apple}
```